# Multiple Inheritance Quirk, or Bug in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I am writing a class which should subclass, amongst other classes, `code.InteractiveInterpreter`. For some reason, one of the methods that that class normally has (`compile`) is not available on its subclasses when you use multiple inheritance.

Single inheritance works fine:

```
>>> from code import InteractiveInterpreter
>>> class Single(InteractiveInterpreter): pass
...
>>> hasattr(Single(), 'compile')
True
```

Multiple inheritance does not:

```
>>> class Double(object, InteractiveInterpreter): pass
...
>>> hasattr(Double(), 'compile')
False
```

Flipped the order around though, it works:

```
>>> class Flipped(InteractiveInterpreter, object): pass
...
>>> hasattr(Flipped(), 'compile')
True
```

Is there some subtle detail of multiple inheritance that I'm unaware of that is preventing `compile` from being inherited in some cases, or is there a bug in Python causing this (given the name of the method in question is also the name of a built-in function, I feel like this might be possible.)

I'm trying to reproduce the issue with a class other than `InteractiveInterpreter` but am unable to... this works fine:

```
>>> class Original():
...     def compile(self): pass
...
>>> class Secondary(object, Original): pass
...
>>> hasattr(Secondary(), 'compile')
True
```

I'm using Python 2.7.11, 32 bit, on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure `Flipped` produced the given results?

I get the following with a similar setup,

```
>>> from code import InteractiveInterpreter
>>> class Flipped(InteractiveInterpreter, object): pass
... 
>>> hasattr(Flipped(), 'compile')
True
```

Based on the [source of the module](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/code.py), `compile` is *not a method* of the class but an *instance attribute* created on object initialization. It would make sense that inheriting from `object` first would not provide the attribute because it's `__init__` is defined and the subclass doesn't call `InteractiveInterpreter.__init__` to assign the attribute.

Comment: I had a typo when I tried. I mistakenly did `hasattr(Flipped, 'compile')` (missing `()`, so checking the instance instead). I've updated the question to mention that that actually works.

Comment: This still isn't clear to me - why isn't the `__init__` method for `InteractiveInterpreter` being called if the bases are arranged the other way in the class definition? Does `object.__init__` not call super?

Comment: It would appear that `object.__init__` does not call super... further, it only seems to be a problem if anything listed after it in bases is an old style class (as `InteractiveInterpreter` is).

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Python will follow MRO for method calls and will stop when it finds a superclass providing the method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly know where the problem lies, but one workaround is to explicitly call the constructor of `InteractiveInterpreter`, where the `compile` method is actually defined:

```
class Double(object, InteractiveInterpreter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        InteractiveInterpreter.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Note that a simply calling to `super(Double, self).__init__(...)` does not suffice (at least in my environment). However, this works for me

```
>>> hasattr(Flipped(), 'compile')
True
```

My environment:
Python 2.7.11 (default, Jan  5 2016, 12:49:55) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin

Answer (score 0):

It seems like something when you mix object and an old style class

*Python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 14.04*

I checked the code for code.InteractiveInterpreter (it's using an old style class), then did some testing:
(I just imported code, then found the file via code.__file__ )

```
class Klass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.compile = 1

class Klass2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.compile = 1

class BlankObj:
    pass

class BlankObj2(object):
    pass


class Frist(object, Klass):
    pass

class Second(BlankObj, Klass):
    pass

class Thrid(BlankObj, Klass2):
    pass

class Fourth(BlankObj, Klass2):
    pass
```

Then played around with those objects:

```
>>> from testing import Frist, Second, Thrid, Fourth
>>> hasattr(Frist(), 'compile')
False
>>> hasattr(Second(), 'compile')
True
>>> hasattr(Thrid(), 'compile')
True
>>> hasattr(Fourth(), 'compile')
True
>>> 
>>> f = Frist()
>>> dir(f)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
>>> s = Second()
>>> dir(s)
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'compile']
```

Attempting to make a 'Fifth' class, where I inherit from object and Klass2 causes this traceback:

```
>>> class Fifth(object, Klass2):
...     pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases object, Klass2
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, but it's definitely related to mixing object directly with an old style class.

Comment: It seems to me the issue is that `object` doesn't call `super(object, self).__init__`, so `InteractiveInterpreter`'s `__init__` method never gets called. As Jared pointed out, `compile` isn't a proper method, but instead it's a function that gets attached as an instance variable within `InteractiveInterpreter.__init__`. Not sure why they chose to implement it that way.